# Saving individual TensorFlow layers without specifying underlying variables

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a way to save a specific `tf.layer` without having to specify all its underlying variables?

Tensorflow allows the saving of an individual variable:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list={"varName": varName})
saver.save(sess, "path")
```

However, this doesn't work with layers. Using `tf.get_collection` to get the variables associated with a particular layer, then calling the `Saver` constructor results in an error:

```
Saver(var_list={"varName": variableCollection})
```

`ValueError: Slices must all be slices: <tf.Variable 'vars1/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32_ref>`

The only solution I know of is to only pass in a single variable of the layer, but it would much more convienent if I didn't have to loop over all the variables in a layer to save it.

```
Saver(var_list={"varName": variableCollection[0]})
```

Comment: Using `saver = tf.train.Saver()` and `saver.save(sess, 'path')` can save all variables and architectures of a model.

Comment: I indicated that I do not want to save all layers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the object-oriented layers (like tf.layers.Dense) you can call layer.variables to get the variables and then pass them to a saver.

Comment: Can you link some documentation or a code example with that?